# Clear a Specific field in mysql

Tags: mysql

Im trying to do a enlistment system. that uses mysql to register players. i can add players to the diffrent spots but when i want to remove one i would just like the database to find witch one i want to remove and remove that one. There are 6 diffrent spots a player can have.

I have tried a little bit of everything but im no expert on mysql so thats why im here.
this is what i have used to find what row he is in but to find the exact field and remove that i have not managed to figure out.

```
SELECT * FROM enlistment_db WHERE squad_leader = '<@playerID>' or player1 = '<@playerID>' or player2 = '<@playerID>' or player3 = '<@playerID>' or player4 = '<@playerID>' or player5 = '<@playerID>' and active = 1
```

so for example player i want to remove is on player3 but how do i make the bot find witch player it is only having the discord id and clear that field.

Answer (score 0):

Do not save the players in columns like `squad_leader` and `player1` to `player5`. Instead save the player enlistment in a new 1-to-N table. The tables should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE team
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE enlistment
(
    Id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    TeamId INT,
    PlayerId INT,
    IsActive BOOL,
    IsLeader BOOL,

    FOREIGN KEY(TeamId) REFERENCES Team(Id);
);
```

That way you create a new row for each player of a team in the `enlistment` table. And if the player shouldn't be part of that team anymore, delete the row.

Comment: This will not work in my case. I need to find what column the player is in and clear that field. Having a new table with a new row for every player is not doable. There is a lot of other data linked and it's not a static squad the squad changes for every game. and the table is just to know who was in what game and when.  when the game is played the active change to 1 and its now just a log on who played that game.

Comment: @JInxed Then link the enlistment to the `matches` or `game` table, not to the `team` table. But the 1-to-N approach is the same. If necessary, update your question to include the more detailed constrains you have on your data/table.